# Is Invariance of domain an overkill?

Tags: continuity, euclidean-geometry, inverse-function

> Let $X=\Bbb R^{n}$ be the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.
>   Suppose that a map $f:X \to X$ is 
>   a contraction mapping, 
>   i.e., there exists $\delta \in [0,1)$ such that
>   $$
> |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \delta |x-y|
> \ \ \ (x,y \in X).
> $$
>   Set $F(x) := x+f(x)$.
>   Prove that the map $F:X \to X$ is bijective
>   and the inverse mapping of $F$ is continuous.

The injectivity of $F$ is easy to prove. To prove $F$ is surjective, given $y \in X$, if one defines $h:=h_y:X \to X$ by $h(x)=y-f(x)$, then for $x,z \in X$, 
$$||h(x)-h(z)||=||y-f(x)-(y-f(z))||=||f(x)-f(z)||\leq \delta ||x-z||,$$
which means $h_y$ is a contraction on a complete metric space ($X=\Bbb R^{n}$), then $h_y$ has a unique fixed point. Let $x$ be the fixed point of $h_y$, $h(x)=x \iff y-f(x)=x \iff F(x)=y$, it follows that $F$ is onto. We conclude that $F$ is bijective.

> 1. My first question: is there any other way to prove $F$ is surjective without using [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)?

It is easily seen that $F(x)= x+f(x)$ is Lipschitz-continuous hence uniformly continuous hence continuous.
We have proved that $F$ is bijective, by [Invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) $f$ is homeomorphism.
Hence  the inverse mapping of $F$ is continuous.

> 2. My second question: is there any other way to prove that the inverse mapping of $F$ is continuous without using Invariance of domain?

For the first question, it's likely that there is no other way. However, since we're working on a specific topological space $X=\Bbb R^{n}$, I wonder if there are another ways to prove the continuity of inverse mapping of $F$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can prove Banach (for $X=\Bbb R^n$) from the surjectivity of $F$, hence you can hardly avoid either using it or accidentally proving it on the way

Comment: I see. I agree that for the first question using the Banach fixed-point theorem may be the only way. How about the second question?